# sql match more than one row

Tags: sql

i'm not sure of the correct terms to describe this issue correctly so my search came up with many results due to common terms.

i have a table that looks like this:

```
    id  status
    1   finished
    1   finished
    1   finished
    1   skipped
    2   skipped
    2   skipped
    2   finished
    2   finished
    3   finished
    3   skipped
    3   finished
    3   skipped
    4   skipped
    4   skipped
    4   skipped
    4   skipped
    5   finished
    5   finished
    5   skipped
    5   skipped
    6   finished
    6   finished
    6   skipped
    6   skipped
```

i want to return the id from the first column (id) if the values in all 4 rows containing that id have "skipped" in the second column (status). if only 1 or 2 or 3 contain skipped, then not interested.

so, for the table above, the result will be: 4

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'skipped';
```

This does not check for exactly four rows.  If that is important add `and count(*) = 4` to the `having` clause.

Comment: Really nice solution.

Comment: yep - very elegant solution. this works well. thank you very much.